# Gatsby anchor link / scrollTo hiding the page above the displayed element

Tags: scroll, gatsby, anchor

I am using Gatsby for the first time and I have started with the Cara starter template.

I have added a link to the hero that would scroll to the next sections (projects) when clicked.

The link does take you to the next section, however the scroll bar remains scrolled all the way to the top of the bar. Meaning that you cannot scroll back up the page. (Strangely now when you scroll to the bottom of the page, the footer is not aligned with the bottom of the page, but you can now scroll all the way back to the top of the page again.)

I tried using various techniques; a standard  anchor tag referencing an id, using `gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll` to `scrollTo()` the element, and all have this same end result.

I'm not sure what is causing this behaviour, but maybe it is something to do with the layout or some conflicting scrolling or offsetting. I would appreciate any help to get me back on track.

I have hosted what I have done so far, so that you can see the issue I am having:
https://portfoliositemain36740.gatsbyjs.io/

Comment: The "View Projects" link does scroll for me :/

Comment: @FerranBuireu as mentioned the link does scroll, but try scrolling back up to the top of the page and you will notice the issue. I have just solved my problem, after struggling all day, by looking at the https://react-spring.io/components/parallax as this seems to be causing the issue. I had to use the ref.current.scrollTo(page) to go to the correct part of the page. I might try to tidy the question and self answer with my findings, in the hope it helps others

Comment: Sure! Feel free to add your own question